# Display polygon colours as percent reflectance of sunlight

Tags: arcgis-desktop, visualisation

I have a set of polygons which I would like to display in different colours.

The only information I can give on the colours is the percent reflectance of sunlight in different channels, e.g.:

B:  0.45 - 0.51µm, 5.1%

G:  0.53 - 0.59µm, 7.2%

R:  0.64 - 0.67µm, 6.1%

NIR:0.85 - 0.88µm, 38.7%

(Landsat 8 OLI channels)

Is there any chance that I can get an RBG or CIR composite, when the values are stored like this in the attribute table of a shapefile?

Comment: You have lots of GIS software tags but what are you using?  ["You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I use all four softwares and I was searching for a solution in all of them. I would be glad if any of them worked.

Comment: To me this means that you are asking four questions (rather than the one question per question of the [Tour]): "How do I do ... in QGIS?", "How do I do ... in ArcGIS for Desktop?", "How do I do ... in GRASS?" and "How do I do ... in ERDAS IMAGINE?"  What have you tried to do in ArcGIS for Desktop so far?

Comment: Okay, I will ask a separate question for ArcGIS and delete this one. I was looking for a method how to display polygon values based on rgb values in the attribute table.

Comment: Please don't delete this one - just [edit] it to narrow its focus.  Deleting questions feeds into the algorithms that can lead to question bans.

Comment: I think that I have mistaken this as being a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123606/symbolizing-using-rgb-values-from-excel-in-arcgis-for-desktop so I am re-opening.

Comment: Just thinking aloud, if there is a way to colour your polygons based on RGB values stored in the attribute table then assuming you rounded to nearest % then potentially you could generate a layer symbology of 1,000,000 symbols. That's 100R * 100G * 100B. No GIS would support that but it's unlikely you would reach that. You would need to group your reflectance values to reduce the combination down to something a GIS could actually display.

Comment: @Polygeo I think that it IS a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123606/symbolizing-using-rgb-values-from-excel-in-arcgis-for-desktop/123612#123612 and I am afraid for countryman that there is no solution to his problem

Comment: I just followed the links to an old forum page [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1730&t=187747&mc=8#555759) there is some VBA code supplied that appears to solve this problem. It builds the renderer manually. Looks like it attempts to construct every combination which I think could blow up in your face if the data has a huge range of RGB values.

Comment: @radouxju I'll trust your judgement on that more than my own.

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd and for all the other comments. I will definitely try the VBA code. However, sad to here that this quite simple issue is obviously not solvable with the present means.